# split a string and get the last part using C

Tags: c, split

I have a string `"some random data/1000"`. Now, I want the number(`1000`) alone without storing the first part anywhere. I should directly get the last part i.e the number. How to do this in C language?

Here `'/'` is delimiter.

Comment: There we are storing every part. Here I do not need to store the first part. My work is only with the numerical data at the end. Infact, the strings are large to store the first part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, but in your particular case

```
char  string[]      = "some random data/1000";
char *pointerTo1000 = strchr(string, '/');
if (pointerTo1000 != NULL)
{
    pointerTo1000 += 1;
    printf("%s\n", pointerTo1000);
}
```

should output `1000`, if you want to covert it to a number

```
char *endptr;
int value = strtol(pointerTo1000, &endptr, 10);
if (*endptr == '\0')
    printf("converted successfuly: %d\n", value);
```

if `some random data` contains a slash `/` then `strrchr` suggested by [unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28169/unwind) is the right choice, and you can use it exactly as in my example.

Comment: avoid `printf("%s\n", pointerTo1000);` with `pointerTo1000` being NULL. There are systems (e.g. solaris) where that crashes

Answer (score 2):

If you're certain there's only one delimiter, I would simply use [`strrchr()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strrchr)<sup>1</sup> to find it. Then either directly convert the number to integer (using e.g. `strtol()`) or allocate a new string and copy the trailing part of the first in there.

<sup>1</sup> Please note that middle `r`, it's searching *backwards*.